# extends in symfony from multiple children

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a base.html.twig with the basic html.

In the 'base' I have a `{% block body %}{% endblock %}` and a `{% block javascript %}{% endblock %}`

I call a 'form.html.twig' file from the Controller and the template extends the base.html.twig.

The 'form' contains the `<form>` and `</form>` tags and can contain a random numbers of sub templates/form elements:

```
'{% block body %}
   {% for template in templates %}
     {% embed template %}{% endembed %}
   {% endfor %}
 {% endblock %}'
```

The 'template' is perhaps a customer.html.twig, confirm.html.twig, vehicle.html.twig etc. etc. and they all have `{% block body %}` and `{% block javascript %}` - **now for the question**:

The content in the template files aren't moved to the blocks body/javascript. How do I get twig/symfony to move the content in the template files to the respective areas in the 'base.html.twig'?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You wrote "emdebed" instead of "embeded"

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `use` twig tag instead of the `embed` tag like this

```
 {% use template %}
```

See more info here:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html

Comment: It gives me the following error: '...The template references in a "use" statement must be a string in standard.html.twig...'

The template is 'customer.html.twig' or 'vehicle.html.twig'. 

I've dumped the 'template' and it is regular strings?

Comment: Ah, that means that use does not accept a variable as an argument, had forgotten about that. Maybe you can use the template_from_string function to achieve this, but I am not really sure it will work

Comment: Sorry - cannot use that function. Thank you for your time.